# How can I update a Firebase element via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am programming a little app in which you have a score system (like 10 points a user) and I am doing this via the Firebase database.

My problem is, that I don't know how to update my database element which I have created on the beginning. I want to update my point via a Javascript script, which can be triggered.

So this is my current code:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

var users = rootRef.child("users");

var log = document.getElementById('log');

```
    document.getElementById('registerBtn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        var empt1 = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
        var empt2 = document.forms["form1"]["password"].value;
        var empt3 = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;

        if(empt1 == "" || empt2 == "" || empt3 == "" || !document.getElementById("txtemail").checkValidity()){
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
        else{
            $("#registerProgress").show();
            $("#registerBtn").hide();
            //Get email and pass
            const email = txtemail.value;
            const pass = txtpassword.value;
            const username = txtusername.value;
            const auth = firebase.auth();

            const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
            promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
            //users.child(username).set({ name: username });
            users.once('value', function(snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasChild(username)) {
                    users.child(username).set({username: username, points: "100"});
                }
                else {
                    alert("That username is already registered");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking how to update the user record in the firebase only if the user does not already exist?  Assuming firebase 3.x.x:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users');

usersRef.child(username).once('value')
  .then(function (userRecord) {
    if(userRecord.exists()) {
      alert('That username is already registered');
    } else {
      //--> There's a ref in each snapshot
      userRecord.ref.child('username').set(username)
        .then(function () {
          userRecord.ref.child('points').set(100);
        });
    }
  });
```

Add Points:

```
usersRef.child(username).child('points').transaction(function (points) {
  return (points || 0) + 10;
});
```

[Official Reference mentioning transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

NOTE: Do not forget to save a number (100) and not a string ("100") or the incrementer will not work properly.  Good luck.

Comment: but each time a user like wins the level, he should get like 10 points --> and this should be updated in the database

Comment: Updated to do so.

Comment: everything working so on, but I cant update my points, I get this error message _Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined_ 
and this is my edited code: 
`document.getElementById('addPoints').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        
        var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
        
        usersRef.child(username).child('points').transaction(function (points) {
        return (points || 0) + 10;
        });
    });`

Comment: That's from your const username assignment. If the constant is ever empty it'll throw an error. If you're writing for web use you might want to stick with ES5 Javascript or use some helper for ES6.

Very good [ES2015 Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) and [ES5 Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/es5-deprecated/es5).